# CSS formatting - need guidance

Tags: html, css

I need a wee bit of help with css formatting on my website. Please see the provided screenshot, which relates to http://www.zerogravpro.com/.

[css problem http://zerogravpro.com/temp/zgp_formatting.jpg](http://zerogravpro.com/temp/zgp_formatting.jpg)

Problem #1: My orange-background box in the Testimonial sections goes quite a bit lower than I want it. How do I force it to move up, directly beneath the word "Testimonials"?

Problem #2: See the nice "More" button with the green ball and arrow in it? When I tried to use the same exact style down in my Testimonials box, it shows up as just a boring link. I want it to look the same as the button. I'm guessing that the style only gets invoked when it has the right hierarchy, but how can I fix this without messing up any other styles?

I provided the link to my website, so you can view it in Firebug and see exactly what the styles are, etc. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Box below Testimonials is so low because there are two **<br>-Tags** below this line:

```
<p class="dotline"></p>
```

Remove them and it will fit.

And for the more button, you should add the class **more** to this **<p>-Tag** (untested):

```
<div id="testimonial6" style="">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, removing those break tags should have been obvious to me. But I don't understand what you're saying to do on the button. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The more button on top of the page is within a `<p>` with the class `more` (that works because the style is defined like this: `p.more a`. So adding the class `more` to the `p` tags within your testimonials should do the trick to style the link. As I only looked into the code with Safari developer tools: No guarantee that I may have overlooked something. :)

Answer (score 0):

The styles describing the button-like more-element is applied to a paragraph with class="more". However, the paragraph also includes a lot more rules than just the button, so you should try to extract the CSS regarding the button in order to make it reusable.

When it comes to positioning of the lower link, if you want to place it near the header you really need to move it closer to the header in the DOM.

Comment: I tried extracting the styles so I can put the button anywhere (and reuse the button), but then I get things flowing wrong and looking terrible everywhere. I really need someone to post an example of a style that will actually work for that button, and to be able to place it wherever I want.

Answer (score 0):

There's an empty p element with the class of 'more' right above the testimonial box. Remove it and the testimonial box will be pulled up. Give it an appropriate margin top, and it will look good.

As for the button, here's my attempt at it -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/c3vqh/

Comment: Ups, misread your question. Thought you hadn't yet coded the button.

Comment: It's not empty, it's the "More" button up above. If I remove that, the button goes away. It's strange I have to put the button way down where it is in order for it to appear correctly up above. Also, I tried your style and it didn't work--I just got a blank box.